# Android-studio. I have 1 apk working. need to make 3 different app´s. for 3 local tablets

Tags: android

I have 1 simple apk working. (it is not for the internet)
I can changes pictures and text in my apk.
I can copy (unsigned)apk to my phone and it works.
it runs in debug mode.

Question. 
I need to make 3 different app´s with 3 different names. For example app1 app2 and app3. The wireframe/design will be identical but pictures and text will be different.the different app´s should be updated (only pictures and text stings) for each app.

I want create three unique apps from here. three different application ID´s (i think)

All 3 should be able to run and be updated on same device.

Is it flavors I shall use?
or can I create and rename into 3 project (three unique app´s)? I would prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use gradle product flavours. For example, go to your app's `build.gradle` file (find module level file, not top/project level) and inside `android { ... }` section add following lines:

```
productFlavors {
    flava {
        applicationIdSuffix ".flava"
    }
    flavb {
        applicationIdSuffix ".flavb"
    }
    flavc {
        applicationIdSuffix ".flavc"
    }
}
```

That way, you will generate apk with three different package names. So, if your default package id (or, how gradle call it, application id) is com.myapp, you will get three apks with ids com.myapp.flava, com.myapp.flavb and com.myapp.flavc.

The `gradle build` command should generate all three apks. Or, if you are building and pushing the app from Android Studio, open "Build Variants" panel and choose flavor you'd like to push on a device.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: If it helps you solve your issue, mark my answer as such, please :)

Comment: I would like to end with "three different app's". made from one project. I will make all pictures and text different i all three.but wireframe and design is the same for alle three. Is flavor still the way to go ? and why

Comment: It depends on how complex your project is.

You can always add build config param in all three flavors, for example:
`buildConfigField "string", "FLAVOR", "FlavA"` and later in java code you can read it as `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` and check it's value and make decisions.

But more proper way would be to make a module/library with stuff common to all three apps, and then just make different apps defining stuff specific to each single app, but that is not as straight forward to explain here :)

Comment: how do I credit you for your answer, all new to this forum :)